# Usage of Bing SpellChecker into LUIS.ai

Tags: azure, spell-checking, bing, azure-language-understanding

I try to improve LUIS intents prediction accuracy. Because there is an issue when missing one letter leads LUIS to a wrong intent.
I use the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-bing-spellcheck), but still there is no promised key like `alteredQuery` in the JSON returned form LUIS.

**EXPECTATION**:

```
  "query": "bouk me a fliht to kayro",
  "prediction": {
    "alteredQuery": "book me a flight to cairo",
    "topIntent": "book a flight",
    "intents": {
      "book a flight": {
        "score": 0.9480589
      }
      "None": {
        "score": 0.0332136229
      }
    },
    "entities": {}
  }
}
```

**REALITY**:

```
  "query": "bouk me a fliht to kayro",
  "prediction": {
    "topIntent": "book a flight",
    "intents": {
      "book a flight": {
        "score": 0.9480589
      }
      "None": {
        "score": 0.0332136229
      }
    },
    "entities": {}
  }
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
const luisConfig: LuisApplication = {
    applicationId: [APP_ID_GOES_HERE],
    endpointKey: [KEY_GOES_HERE],
    endpoint: [ENDPOINT_GOES_HERE],
};

const recognizerOptions: LuisRecognizerOptionsV2 = {
    apiVersion: 'v2',
    bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey: [KEY_GOES_HERE];
    includeAllIntents: true,
    log: true,
    spellCheck: true,
    log: true,
    includeInstanceData: true
};

const luisRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer(luisConfig, recognizerOptions, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue... if I call the API directly:

```
/luis/prediction/v3.0/apps/<xxxxx>/slots/production/predict?verbose=true&show-all-intents=false&log=true&subscription-key=<xxxxx>&mkt-bing-spell-check-key=<xxxxx>&query=gretings
```

The response have not the object "alteredQuery".

Im also try with more parameters with the same result:

```
https://<xxxxx>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/luis/prediction/v3.0/apps/<xxxxx>/slots/production/predict?verbose=true&show-all-intents=false&log=true&subscription-key=<xxxxx>&spellCheck=true&mkt-bing-spell-check-key=<xxxxx>&bing-spell-check-subscription-key=<xxxxx>&query=gretings
```

If I call directly the BING API with the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key header, they response correctly:

```
https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/spellcheck?text=gretings
```